# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'executionPolicy' does not exist in type 'PowerShellOptions'.ts(2345)

Tags: node.js, angular, powershell, npm, node-modules

I have created a ps script to read VM disk spaces. With the "node-powershell" module, I would like to display the output in angular.

However, I encounter the following error.

**[ERROR]**

```
Argument of type '{ executionPolicy: string; noProfile: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PowerShellOptions'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'executionPolicy' does not exist in type 'PowerShellOptions'.ts(2345)
```

Here is my code:

**[home.component.html]**

```js
        <div>
          <span class="p-as-end">{{ diskSpace }}</span>
        </div>
```

**[home.component.ts]**

```js
import { PowerShell } from 'node-powershell';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  diskSpace: string = '';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDiskSpace();
  }

  async getDiskSpace() {
    const ps = new PowerShell({
      executionPolicy: "Bypass",
      noProfile: true,
    });
  
    const command = PowerShell.command`
    $vms = 'vm1', 'vm2', 'vm3'
    Get-CimInstance -Class win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" -ComputerName $vms |
        Format-Table @(
            'PSComputerName'
            'DeviceId'
            @{n='Size (GB)'; e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB)}} 
            @{n='FreeSpace (GB)'; e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}} 
    )
    `;
  
    const output = await ps.invoke(command);
    ps.dispose();
    
    this.diskSpace = output.raw;
  }
```

For testing, I ran the ps code in my local, and it worked successfully.

However, when applying the code to the whole project, it does not allow me to put `{ executionPolicy: string; noProfile: boolean; }`, which worked in my local testing without any problem.

Any advice, please?

Comment: How do you expect your frontend to execute serverside commands?

Comment: Judging by https://github.com/rannn505/child-shell/blob/328f9408e059289153cf2ee200dde8f7c7fd3eea/playground/index.ts#L44, the properties you're trying to use should be nested inside the `executableOptions` property.